# Is it possible to send app debug signing package to AWS Device Farm in order for them to resign app with it instead of their own package?

Tags: android, android-testing, appium-android, aws-device-farm

We are using AWS Device Farm for running our Appium TestNG automation tests for Android. Our app uses Google Maps and our API returns locations of some stations on the map in order for the user to navigate to them. In order for the app to get a response from API, it needs to be registered on our back-end (application's signing package must be added to the "trust" list).

Our problem with AWS Device Farm is that it resigns Android application with their own package when we upload it to AWS DF.

Because of that our API doesn't recognize that app and doesn't send the response to it, so on AWS DF device we get neither map nor stations, but just "gray" screen. In that state our app is untestable.

In one post on the AWS DF forum, they mentioned (3 years ago) that AWS is working on the possibility for users to send their own debug packages for AWS DF to resign the app using them.

This would solve our problem, but there is no updated info on it neither on forum nor documentation. I tried asking this on the AWS DF forum, but it's almost a month gone and there is no answer to it, not even some advice or suggestion.

Does anyone know is it possible to send a debug signing package to AWS DF for resigning the app with it or maybe some other way for apps that must be signed with specific package to work on AWS DF?

Answer (score 0):

You can [skip the app resigning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/skip-app-re-signing-on-private-devices.html) in Device Farm using their [private offering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/working-with-private-devices.html). However, this offering is much more expensive than the default metered public offering. The [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/) points us to this email for more info about the price: 
`aws-devicefarm-support@amazon.com`

Otherwise, this is still expected behavior as discussed in the FAQs.
https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faqs/

> Q: Do you modify my app?
>   On Android, we resign the app. This may break functionality that depends on the app signature, such as the Google Maps Android API. It may also trigger anti-piracy and anti-tamper detection available from products such as DexGuard. For built-in tests, we may modify the manifest to include permissions required to capture and save screenshots.

Comment: Tnx for the answer. However, I remember reading in one post on the AWS DF forum, that AWS is working on the possibility for users to send their own debug packages for AWS DF to resign the app using them. But, since this was 3 years old post I guess it still isn't and won't be done, especially if they offer no-signing your app if you pay more money. So I guess for us as a company this testing with using AWS Device Farm lead to a conclusion that it's totally useless for our application, so we'll be switching to some more reliable device farm since there are a lot of them.